# ggplot stat_summary text subscript

Tags: r, ggplot2

Assume a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame("Method" = rep(c("Method1", "Method2", "Method3", "Method4", "Method5"), each = 3, times = 1),
                 "Type" = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 5),
                 "Value" = c(runif(5, 0, 1), runif(5, 0.2, 1.2), runif(5, 0.4, 1.4)))
```

I created a boxplot

```
get_box_stats <- function(y, upper_limit = max(df$Value) * 1.42) {
  return(data.frame(
    y = upper_limit,
    label = paste(
      "N =", length(y), "\n",
      "Q1 =", round(quantile(y, 0.25), 2), "\n",
      "M =", round(median(y), 2), "\n",
      "Q3 =", round(quantile(y, 0.75), 2), "\n"
    )
  ))
}

ggplot(df, aes(factor(Type), Value)) +
  labs(fill = "Method") +
  stat_summary(size = 4.6, fun.data = get_box_stats, geom = "text", position = position_dodge(.9),
               hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, aes(group = factor(Type)))+
  geom_boxplot(coef = 0, aes(fill = factor(Type))) + theme_classic()+ 
  theme(legend.position = "top", axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.title=element_text(size = 15), 
        legend.text=element_text(size = 15)) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = factor(Type)), dotsize = 0.8, binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center',
               position = position_dodge(0.75))+
  xlab("Method")
```

that looks like this
[image]

**Question:** how to change `Q1` to `Q₁`? I've tried:

- `expression(Q[1])`
- `bquote(Q[1])`
- simply pasting ₁

but none of them work.

**UPDATE:** using `Q\u2081 =` doesn't render a subscript, instead there appears an empty square. However, it works when not used in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Unicode subscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

get_box_stats <- function(y, upper_limit = max(df$Value) * 1.42) {
  return(data.frame(
    y = upper_limit,
    label = paste(
      "N =", length(y), "\n",
      "Q\u2081 =", round(quantile(y, 0.25), 2), "\n",
      "M =", round(median(y), 2), "\n",
      "Q\u2083 =", round(quantile(y, 0.75), 2), "\n"
    )
  ))
}

ggplot(df, aes(factor(Type), Value)) +
  labs(fill = "Method") +
  stat_summary(size = 4.6, fun.data = get_box_stats, geom = "text", position = position_dodge(.9),
               hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, aes(group = factor(Type)))+
  geom_boxplot(coef = 0, aes(fill = factor(Type))) + theme_classic()+ 
  theme(legend.position = "top", axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.title=element_text(size = 15), 
        legend.text=element_text(size = 15)) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = factor(Type)), dotsize = 0.8, binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center',
               position = position_dodge(0.75))+
  xlab("Method")
#> Bin width defaults to 1/30 of the range of the data. Pick better value with
#> `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, however what I end up getting is an empty square instead of a subscript.

Comment: Hm. Looks like an encoding issue. When I render using the `reprex` package I also get only a square. But interestingly I works fine when I render a `print("\u2082")`. Maybe a ggplot2 issue?

Comment: I just googled a bit. Could you try with explicitly setting the family argument, i.e. `stat_summary(..., family = "sans")`. At least on my machine running Mac OS this fixed the issue with rendering using `reprex`. And as a reference: Got the hint from https://michaelbach.de/2020/03/22/ggplotAndUnicode.html

Comment: unfortunately, this still doesn't work. but I appreciate the effort.